# php взять кириллическую подстроку

Tags: php

У меня есть строка на русском и я хочу взять первые 6 символов из нее. Как я это делаю:

```
<?php

$surname = "Строкастрока";

$surname = substr($surname, 0 , 7) . "..."; 

echo $surname;
?>
```

Но вывод:

```
Стр�...
```

Как мне взять подстроку без такого символа? На английских словах все работает корректно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте mb_substr() вместо substr().